# Measure theory convergence in Lp.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

We assume that $\mu(E)<\infty$. Let $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $f$ be real measurable functions on $E$, and let $p \in[1, \infty)$. Show that the conditions
(i) $f_n \longrightarrow f$, $\mu$ a.e.,
(ii) there exists a real $r>p$ such that $\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int\left|f_n\right|^r \mathrm{~d} \mu<\infty$, imply that $f_n \longrightarrow f$ in $L^p$.\
I need some hint on how I can use these ideas because I got scattered and unable to use any idea properly. Seems like using dominated convergence theorem, yet confused about sup thing here.

Comment: What you want is uniform integrability. The condition you mentioned is a sufficient condition for the family $\{|f_{n}|^{p}\}_{n}$ to be uniformly integrable. Then you can  use that if $g_{n}\to g$ a.e. and $g_{n}$ is uniformly integrable then $g_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}g$. (i.e. $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{p}}f\iff |f_{n}|^{p}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}|f|^{p})$

Answer (score 2):

The following is a detailed sketch.

By Fatou's lemma $f\in L^r$ so that $g_n:=f_n-f \in L^r$ satisfies all our conditions, with pointwise limit 0. Define $M:=\sup_n \int |g_n|^r\, d\mu$.

For a fixed $t>0$, we have, using Hölder's inequality:
\begin{align}
\int_E |g_n|^p\, d\mu & = \int_{\{ |g_n|\geq t\}} |g_n|^p\, d\mu + \int_{\{ |g_n|<t\}}|g_n|^p\, d\mu\\
& \leq \mu(\{ |g_n|\geq t\})^{(1-p/r)p}\left(\int_{\{ |g_n|\geq t\}} |g_n|^r\, d\mu\right)^{p^2/r} + t^p\mu(E)\\
& \leq M^{p^2/r}\mu(\{ |g_n|\geq t\})^{(1-p/r)p} + t^p\mu(E).
\end{align}
The first term goes to 0 (for each fixed $t$!) since $g_n\to 0$ in measure. Now just pick $t>0$ such that the right hand side is as small as you need.

Comment: is it supposed to be $\mu(\{ |g_n|\geq t\})^{(1-p/r)}\left(\int_{\{ |g_n|\geq t\}} |g_n|^r\, d\mu\right)^{p/r}$?